# SingleOrNewIdentified(o => o.prop, value), setting o.prop when new

Tags: c#, lambda, setter

I'd like a C# `SingleOrNewIdentified(o => o.prop, value)` function, responsible for returning a new `o` with `o.prop = value` preset when `Any(o.prop == value)` is not found. Unfortunately my understanding of expressions and lambdas is poor.

I frequently find myself needing to uniquely set just the one identifier (e.g. emailAddress, oauthId, GUID, natural key) before using a new EF object in a write-many manner. This write-once assignment often makes me shuffle some blocks around in a less-than-clear way.

It seems likely that it can be done since I'd be fine with reflection. I wouldn't want to defeat type checking in consumers of this function in any way, though.

Warnings about this idea are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static T SingleOrNewIdentified<T, TProp>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> propExpr, TProp value) where T : class, new()
{
    var property = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)propExpr.Body).Member;
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var eqExpr = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(paramExpr, property), Expression.Constant(value));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eqExpr, paramExpr);

    T maybe = queryable.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    if (maybe != null) return maybe;

    T @default = new T();
    property.SetValue(@default, value);

    return @default;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lee. I've learned a lot from your answer. Two questions if you don't mind. 1) When does Expression.Constant go away? 2) Although I only needed this on EF, is there any reason I couldn't also provide less efficient fallbacks (e.g. IEnumerable)?

Comment: @shannon - 1. I'm not sure what you mean about `Expression.Constant` 'going away'. 2. You could convert this to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable`, the simplest change would be to call `Compile` on `predicate` and pass that to `Enumerable.SingleOrDefault`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want but it seems you can do it this way: if your collection is `null`, assign a default:

```
var foo = /*db.FooTable.*/SingleOrDefault(x => /*your where clause*/) ?? new Foo
                                              {
                                                  EmailMember = "me@foo.now"   
                                              };
```

Comment: +1: Yeah, that's very similar to what I have now. I personally thought it lacked clarity, and I thought a lambda could clean it up. But then because I don't really know what a hammer looks like, everything could be a hammer.

Comment: @shannon: personally I like this approche because it doesn't need more code to do the job. It just keeps it simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's not what I was looking for, but I thought I should note a related functionality for EF (update-or-create-by-indentity) for simplifying attaching at the end rather than beginning of your process, for entity keys only:

```
db.Attach(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It's been easy for me to forget that EF will do this work for you, but it maps especially well to UIs where create and update are very similar. You have to wait for SaveChanges() for a generated entity key of course.